# Using Common Table Expression (CTE) in JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, sql, jpa, common-table-expression, jpa-criteria

```
WITH cte AS
(
select
        A.A_ID,
        B.Lib,
        A.Lib,
        C.Lib,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM X WHERE A.A_ID = X.A_ID) AS countX,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM Y WHERE A.A_ID = Y.A_ID) AS countY,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM Z WHERE A.A_ID = Z.A_ID) AS countZ
    from
        A
    left outer join
        C
            on A.C_ID=C.C_ID
    left outer join
        B
            on A.B_ID=B.B_ID
) select * from cte where countX = 2 AND countY = 3
    Order BY 
    countZ DESC;
```

I know how to create the sql query inside the CTE but I don't have any idea how to create the CTE in JPA Criteria API (`WITH cte AS (...) SELECT * FROM cte`).

Comment: I don't think JPA supports modern SQL, let alone the crippled criteria API

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What about this syntax: `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ...)`

Comment: doesn´t support subselects either, only in WHERE/HAVING clauses