# How to use CTE expression WITH clause in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, common-table-expression

I want to write a recursive query in SQL Server. So I am using CTE. Query is working properly in SSMS but when I am trying to use the same CTE in JPA as native SQL it gives an error:

> Invalid name column Id.

The entity (which I am using in CTE to fetch data recursively) has `@Id @Column(name="pk_id") private int Id` field.

I also followed this SOQ : [cte sql to simple subset query for JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889514/cte-sql-to-simple-subset-query-for-jpa)

But still getting error as invalid name column Id.

I have never used CTE before. How can this be fixed?

Comment: CTE doesn't work with JPQL, you need to use the SQL instead.

Comment: How to use recursive SQL but ?

Comment: Just put the SQL in and set `native-query` to `true`.

Comment: Yes, I tried. `@Query(value = "sql here",nativeQuery = true)` and got same error. But in `native-query` I tried the SQL which to SQL mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889514/cte-sql-to-simple-subset-query-for-jpa). Is that okay ?

Comment: The problem is if you are matching the result to a JPA entity your resulting columns have to match the mapping. Looks like that is off in your result set.

Comment: @M.Deinum,Yes. Made changes and now worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the SQL query in JPA Repositories since the @Query annotation takes native query as well. For that, you need to specify the SQL query in the value parameter and **nativeQuery** is true as follow.

You can write CTE queries as well.

```
public interface ISomeRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {


    @Query(value = "SQL QUERY NEED TO BE WRITTEN HERE", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Long> getEntityIds();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using recursive query,creating view might be a way to use it in JPA

For Example,create a view like below:

```
CREATE VIEW RECUSRSIVE_QUERY_VIEW
AS
[Your Recursive CTE]
```

Then write a Entity class mapping to RECUSRSIVE_QUERY_VIEW:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RECUSRSIVE_QUERY_VIEW")
public class RecursiveQueryView {
  //Declare column and getter/setter
}
```

Then you should be able to use JpaRepository With this Entity:

```
interface RecursiveQueryViewJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<RecursiveQueryView,String> {
}
```

Hope this help